# c# Registry can't open Subkey with {}

Tags: c#

Here is my code

```
RegistryKey = regsohr;
regsohr = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks\{DFDC1B83-7FD3-4C77-8CD1-7391D1680ACA}");
sw.WriteLine(regsohr.GetValue("Path"));
```

It can't get into {DFDC1B83-7FD3-4C77-8CD1-7391D1680ACA}.
But when I delete that line everything works fine.
Anyone has any ideas why it can't open this SubKey?
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Remove the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` part - you've already got `Registry.LocalMachine` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.
I have messed up with "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE".

```
regsohr = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks\{DFDC1B83-7FD3-4C77-8CD1-7391D1680ACA}");
```

Fixed it

```
regsohr = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks\{DFDC1B83-7FD3-4C77-8CD1-7391D1680ACA}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , for example i put it in a Label to check if it works

```
{
    string readValue;
    readValue = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue
     (@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache", "Tasks",Nothing);
    Label6.Text = readValue;
}
```